# curl from cmd to php

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm new in this of curl and I try to convert this command:

```
curl -k -v -u "user:password" -X POST
-d'{"username":"testuser","password":"testpassword"}' -H 'Content-Type:application/json'
url
```

from cmd 
to php and i did this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json"));  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("username"=>"testuser","password"=>"testpassword"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "url");
$x=  curl_exec($ch);
echo $x;
var_dump($x);
curl_close($ch);
```

but the web service not return nothing(it's supposed to have return me  json),whats wrong?
pd: i try to connect to a fortiauthenticator and sorry by mi bad english

---

update

hi, everybody, thanks MonkeyZeus and hindmost , for your help, this is the code correct

```
$ch = curl_init();
    $json = json_encode(array("username"=>"testuser2","password"=>"testpassword"));//name and pass of user to create
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");//name and pass of webservices
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json"));  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ip_fortiauthenticator/api/version/localusers/");
    $x = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $x;
    var_dump($x);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

i hope somebody who fight with the FortiAuthenticator can be help this code, it's for a FA version 3

Comment: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` are wrong, you need to provide an array, not a string, like this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('username'=>'testuser','password'=>'testpassword'));`

Comment: i try that,but didn't work

Comment: I think you can remove `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");`

Comment: And remove `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json"));`

Comment: Right before `curl_close($ch);` try placing `echo curl_error($ch);`

Comment: You have to remove `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION`, `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` options

Comment: @hindmost how do you know? PHP manual: `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION: The SSL version (2 or 3) to use. By default PHP will try to determine this itself, although in some cases this must be set manually.`

Comment: i'm start to hate fortinet T-T,now return me this "string(0) "" ", with all the changes that you recommend me

Comment: Does the URL use `HTTPS`? If not then you do not need the SSL stuff

Comment: the https is necessary because is hardware type radius and "Content-Type:application/json" indicate fa(
FortiAuthenticator ) the type a response it return

Answer (score 0):

When you set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option with an array, CURL will force `"Content-Type"` header to `"multipart/form-data"`. But you need to pass POST data as JSON. So you have to set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option to JSON-encoded string.
Somehow like this:

```
$json = json_encode(array("username"=>"testuser","password"=>"testpassword"));
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json"));  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
$x = curl_exec($ch);
echo $x;
var_dump($x);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: i'm try the code,but no create the user in  FA and not return nothing